# How to place text on the same page as title page

Tags: formatting, titles

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}  % Single-spacing, double-spacing, e.g., \setstretch{1.0}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{endnotes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document Dimensions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.6in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\setstretch{1.6}


\date{}

\begin{document}









\begin{titlepage}

\title{some title}

\author{blah\thanks{blah}, blah\thanks{blah}, blah\thanks{blah}, blah\thanks{\textbf{Corresponding author:} blah}, and blah\thanks{blah}}


\textbf{Keywords:} Performance Measure, Performance Manipulation, Return Smoothing

\textbf{JEL Classification:} C10, G10, G20

\maketitle


\end{titlepage}



\end{document}
```

The above produces the following:

[image]

[image]

However I want to have the text that says JEL classification and Keywords right ABOVE the author affiliations on the title page, but when I compile I keep getting them on separate pages. How can I make them appear on the same page?

Comment: Use `{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}` rather than just `\maketitle`.

Comment: One should not use  `\maketitle` within the `titlepage` environment. To customise the \maketitle command, you can take a look at the `titling` package. It define 4 `\maketitlehook` so that maketitle can print additional elements.